# Importance of indenting XML file

Tags: xml

Is it necessary to indent the XML tags in a XML file for successful parsing of the file?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

No, [the XML spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#sec-white-space) define whitespace like this:

> In editing XML documents, it is often convenient to use "white space"
>   (spaces, tabs, and blank lines) to set apart the markup for greater
>   readability. Such white space is typically not intended for inclusion
>   in the delivered version of the document. On the other hand,
>   "significant" white space that should be preserved in the delivered
>   version is common, for example in poetry and source code.

So in terms of parsing the document, no. You can use as much or as little as you want or need and it will *parse* correctly. This may or may not change the meaning of the XML document, however.

Indenting XML tags is never required for *parsing*. However, the point of XML is to be human as well as machine readable, so indentation is generally worth having, as it makes it far easier for human readers to work with and take in the structure at a glance.

Comment: It's not *completely* ignored. If there is any whitespace between elements in (X)HTML rendering, it will be interpreted as a space. If there isn't, it won't.

Comment: Weird situation. Any XML compliant reader should ignore whitespaces in between tags... So human-friendly xml parsers shouldn't follow the standard... Mmmmm... Was the standard made by humans?

Answer (score 10):

Short, short, short answer: Nope.

Longer answer: It depends on your application whether or not whitespace is significant. If you indent your XML file you add whitespace which *sometimes* has meaning to the application processing the data contained.

But for parsing the XML file? Whitespace does not influence the parse-ability, no. See the [whitespace handling section](http://www.w3.org/TR/2008/REC-xml-20081126/#sec-white-space) of the XML specification.

Answer (score 7):

No, the indentation does not matter in XML documents.