# XamlReader.Parse(somestring) as Section - adding extra <Run></Run> blocks

Tags: c#, xml, richtextbox

Can someone help me with this?
I am reading xml from file and trying to post to a RichTextBox.

Here's the input from xml:

```
<Section xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" xml:space="preserve" TextAlignment="Left" LineHeight="Auto" IsHyphenationEnabled="False" xml:lang="en-us" FlowDirection="LeftToRight" NumberSubstitution.CultureSource="User" NumberSubstitution.Substitution="AsCulture" FontFamily="Segoe UI" FontStyle="Normal" FontWeight="Normal" FontStretch="Normal" FontSize="12" Foreground="#FFFFFFFF" Typography.StandardLigatures="True" Typography.ContextualLigatures="True" Typography.DiscretionaryLigatures="False" Typography.HistoricalLigatures="False" Typography.AnnotationAlternates="0" Typography.ContextualAlternates="True" Typography.HistoricalForms="False" Typography.Kerning="True" Typography.CapitalSpacing="False" Typography.CaseSensitiveForms="False" Typography.StylisticSet1="False" Typography.StylisticSet2="False" Typography.StylisticSet3="False" Typography.StylisticSet4="False" Typography.StylisticSet5="False" Typography.StylisticSet6="False" Typography.StylisticSet7="False" Typography.StylisticSet8="False" Typography.StylisticSet9="False" Typography.StylisticSet10="False" Typography.StylisticSet11="False" Typography.StylisticSet12="False" Typography.StylisticSet13="False" Typography.StylisticSet14="False" Typography.StylisticSet15="False" Typography.StylisticSet16="False" Typography.StylisticSet17="False" Typography.StylisticSet18="False" Typography.StylisticSet19="False" Typography.StylisticSet20="False" Typography.Fraction="Normal" Typography.SlashedZero="False" Typography.MathematicalGreek="False" Typography.EastAsianExpertForms="False" Typography.Variants="Normal" Typography.Capitals="Normal" Typography.NumeralStyle="Normal" Typography.NumeralAlignment="Normal" Typography.EastAsianWidths="Normal" Typography.EastAsianLanguage="Normal" Typography.StandardSwashes="0" Typography.ContextualSwashes="0" Typography.StylisticAlternates="0">
    <Paragraph TextAlignment="Center">
      <Run FontSize="21.75" TextDecorations="Underline">title</Run>
    </Paragraph>
    <Paragraph TextAlignment="Center">
      <Run FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="12.75">Some textSome textSome textSome textSome textSome text</Run>
    </Paragraph>
    <Paragraph TextAlignment="Center">
      <Run FontSize="12.75" TextDecorations="Underline">Some textSome textSome textSome textSome textSome textSome text</Run>
    </Paragraph>
  </Section>
```

Here's the code:

```
string strXmlText=null;

        if (page.Content != null)
        {
            using (StringWriter sw = new StringWriter())
            {
                using (System.Xml.XmlTextWriter tx = new System.Xml.XmlTextWriter(sw))
                {
                    page.Content.WriteTo(tx);
                    strXmlText = sw.ToString();
                }
            }

            Section sec = XamlReader.Parse(strXmlText) as Section;

            editor.mainRTB.Document.Blocks.Add(sec);
        }
```

Before and after each **Run** tag (that you see in the xml above) an extra **Run** tag is being added.  I can see that strXmlText is sans the extra Run tag but after the XamlReader.Parse it is there.

Comment: Some further clarification:  page.Content is an XElement - that is converted to a string.  This works.  I get the xml above with no extra run tags but in a readable string.  When I do XamlReader.Parse to a Section, that's when the extra <Run> tags appear...  My rich text box displays extra lines (i.e. 1 blank line between Title and sometext is now 2 blank lines...

Answer (score 0):

Update:  seems the problem is in the conversion to xaml from the richtextbox.

using this code:

```
TextRange range = new TextRange(rt.Document.ContentStart, rt.Document.ContentEnd);
MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
range.Save(stream, DataFormats.Xaml);
string xamlText = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(stream.ToArray());
return xamlText;
```

upon inspecting the xamlText string, I see the extra Run tags.  I think it is the format passed in to the Save...

Any suggestions?

Actually here is my code (above is from another stackoverflow answer):

```
private string CreateXamlFromRTB()
    {
        string xamlText = null;
        TextRange tr = new TextRange(editor.mainRTB.Document.ContentStart, editor.mainRTB.Document.ContentEnd);

        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
        tr.Save(ms, DataFormats.Xaml);
        xamlText = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(ms.ToArray());
            //xamlText = ASCIIEncoding.Default.GetString(ms.ToArray());

        return xamlText;
    }
```

Update #2:
The xamlText string is passed to a function that converts it to an XElement to be stored in xml...like such (where content is a string):

```
newXml.Add(new XElement(XName.Get("Content"), XElement.Parse(content)));
```

content looks like the ... xml above...

Comment: That other answer may not be 100% correct; [`Encoding.ASCII`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding.ascii%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) replaces non-ASCII unicode characters with `?`.

Comment: The reason that you see the extra lines is that `XamlReader.Parse()` seems to interpret the cosmetic whitespace and newline indentation characters as actual flow document content.  Solution is to create unformatted XML as you have found.  I'm not sure why this isn't a problem in precompiled XAML resource files -- maybe the XAML-to-BAML compiler strips the whitespaces?

Comment: Except that I need the formatting from the richtextbox...  Whatever the user wants it to look like should be preserved.

Comment: I don't mean rich text formatting -- I mean purely cosmetic [XML White Space](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#sec-white-space) which is inserted into the XML for human readability and generally [should be ignored](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12526438/importance-of-indenting-xml-file) by XML parsers.  For some reason, it's not getting ignored by `XamlReader.Parse()`.  Your `CreateXamlFromRTB` actually creates unindented XML which is why it fixes your problem.  (Try displaying the string with `Debug.WriteLine()` and you will see it's all on a single line.)