# Converting csv into a standardized xml format using R

Tags: r, excel, xml, csv, dublin-core

I'm trying to take biological data saved in a .csv format and convert it into a specific xml format set by Darwin Core standards (an extension of Dublin Core). The data are set up in rows of observation records with headers in the first row. I need to repackage the data with Darwin Core standard XML tags using a basic XML tree/schema. The purpose is to standardize the data and make it readily available to load into any kind of database program.

I am a biologist, so I'm fairly new in computer programming and code. I would like to write something in R or excel that can do this repackaging step automatically so I don't have to manually reenter thousands of records.

I have tried using the developer tools in excel 365 to save the .csv as an .xml  file, but it seems like I would have to develop the xml tree or schema in a text editor program first. Also, it seems like the xml add-ons that I would use are no longer available. I have downloaded the free text editor called "Brackets" build 1.14 to write some simple xml. I also have RStudio version 1.1.419 with the XML package downloaded to potentially write a script with R version 3.4.3. I've read up on all the Darwin Core Terms and basic XML syntax and rules, but I don't really know where to start.

This is an example of the data in simple .csv format:

```
type,institutionCode,collectionCode,catalogNumber,scientificName,individualCount,datasetID
PhysicalObject,ANSP,PH,123,"Cryptantha gypsophila Reveal & C.R. Broome",12,urn:lsid:tim.lsid.tdwg.org:collections:1
PhysicalObject,ANSP,PH,124,"Buxbaumia piperi",2,urn:lsid:tim.lsid.tdwg.org:collections:1
```

This is what the records should look like as an end product:

```
    [<?xml version="1.0"?>
<dwr:SimpleDarwinRecordSet
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://rs.tdwg.org/dwc/xsd/simpledarwincore/  http://rs.tdwg.org/dwc/xsd/tdwg_dwc_simple.xsd"
    xmlns:dcterms="http://purl.org/dc/terms/"
    xmlns:dwc="http://rs.tdwg.org/dwc/terms/"
    xmlns:dwr="http://rs.tdwg.org/dwc/xsd/simpledarwincore/">
    <dwr:SimpleDarwinRecord>
        <dcterms:type>PhysicalObject</dcterms:type>
        <dwc:institutionCode>ANSP</dwc:institutionCode>
        <dwc:collectionCode>PH</dwc:collectionCode>
        <dwc:catalogNumber>123</dwc:catalogNumber>
        <dwc:scientificName>Cryptantha gypsophila reveal &amp; C.R. Boome</dwc:scientificName>
        <dwc:individualCount>12</dwc:individualCount>
        <dwc:datasetID>urn:lsid:tim.lsid.tdwg.org:collections:1</dwc:datasetID>
    </dwr:SimpleDarwinRecord>
    <dwr:SimpleDarwinRecord>
        <dcterms:type>PhysicalObject</dcterms:type>
        <dwc:institutionCode>ANSP</dwc:institutionCode>
        <dwc:collectionCode>PH</dwc:collectionCode>
        <dwc:catalogNumber>124</dwc:catalogNumber>
        <dwc:scientificName>Buxbaumia piperi</dwc:scientificName>
        <dwc:individualCount>2</dwc:individualCount>
        <dwc:datasetID>urn:lsid:tim.lsid.tdwg.org:collections:1</dwc:datasetID>
    </dwr:SimpleDarwinRecord>
</dwr:SimpleDarwinRecordSet>]
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done in a number of ways. Here, I go for the stringi solution because it's easy to read what the inputs are.

The code below imports the data, writes the first part of the XML, then writes `SimpleDarwinRecord`s for each line and finally the last part of the file. `unlink` is there to clean up before anything is appended to the file. If indentation matters ([apparently it doesn't](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12526459/322912)), you may need to tweak the template a bit.

This could also be done using a Jinja2 template and Python.

```
library(stringr)

xy <- read.table(text = 'type,institutionCode,collectionCode,catalogNumber,scientificName,individualCount,datasetID
PhysicalObject,ANSP,PH,123,"Cryptantha gypsophila Reveal & C.R. Broome",12,urn:lsid:tim.lsid.tdwg.org:collections:1
PhysicalObject,ANSP,PH,124,"Buxbaumia piperi",2,urn:lsid:tim.lsid.tdwg.org:collections:1', header = TRUE,
                 sep = ",")

unlink("output.txt")
outfile <- file(description = "output.txt", open = "at")

writeLines('[<?xml version="1.0"?>
<dwr:SimpleDarwinRecordSet
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://rs.tdwg.org/dwc/xsd/simpledarwincore/  http://rs.tdwg.org/dwc/xsd/tdwg_dwc_simple.xsd"
    xmlns:dcterms="http://purl.org/dc/terms/"
    xmlns:dwc="http://rs.tdwg.org/dwc/terms/"
    xmlns:dwr="http://rs.tdwg.org/dwc/xsd/simpledarwincore/">', con = outfile)

writeLines(str_glue('<dwr:SimpleDarwinRecord>
        <dcterms:type>{xy$type}</dcterms:type>
        <dwc:institutionCode>{xy$institutionCode}</dwc:institutionCode>
        <dwc:collectionCode>{xy$collectionCode}</dwc:collectionCode>
        <dwc:catalogNumber>{xy$catalogNumber}</dwc:catalogNumber>
        <dwc:scientificName>{xy$scientificName}</dwc:scientificName>
        <dwc:individualCount>{xy$individualCount}</dwc:individualCount>
        <dwc:datasetID>{xy$datasetID}</dwc:datasetID>
      </dwr:SimpleDarwinRecord>'), con = outfile)

writeLines(
  '</dwr:SimpleDarwinRecordSet>]',
  con = outfile)

close(outfile)
```

This is the result:

```
[<?xml version="1.0"?>
<dwr:SimpleDarwinRecordSet
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://rs.tdwg.org/dwc/xsd/simpledarwincore/  http://rs.tdwg.org/dwc/xsd/tdwg_dwc_simple.xsd"
    xmlns:dcterms="http://purl.org/dc/terms/"
    xmlns:dwc="http://rs.tdwg.org/dwc/terms/"
    xmlns:dwr="http://rs.tdwg.org/dwc/xsd/simpledarwincore/">
<dwr:SimpleDarwinRecord>
  <dcterms:type>PhysicalObject</dcterms:type>
  <dwc:institutionCode>ANSP</dwc:institutionCode>
  <dwc:collectionCode>PH</dwc:collectionCode>
  <dwc:catalogNumber>123</dwc:catalogNumber>
  <dwc:scientificName>Cryptantha gypsophila Reveal & C.R. Broome</dwc:scientificName>
  <dwc:individualCount>12</dwc:individualCount>
  <dwc:datasetID>urn:lsid:tim.lsid.tdwg.org:collections:1</dwc:datasetID>
</dwr:SimpleDarwinRecord>
<dwr:SimpleDarwinRecord>
  <dcterms:type>PhysicalObject</dcterms:type>
  <dwc:institutionCode>ANSP</dwc:institutionCode>
  <dwc:collectionCode>PH</dwc:collectionCode>
  <dwc:catalogNumber>124</dwc:catalogNumber>
  <dwc:scientificName>Buxbaumia piperi</dwc:scientificName>
  <dwc:individualCount>2</dwc:individualCount>
  <dwc:datasetID>urn:lsid:tim.lsid.tdwg.org:collections:1</dwc:datasetID>
</dwr:SimpleDarwinRecord>
</dwr:SimpleDarwinRecordSet>]
```